# Dynamodb record not updating through for loop

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

I'm currently using dynamoose for managing records in dynamodb.

from my client I'm receiving a collection of insiders

```
insiders: [
  { uid: '123', name: 'Insider A' },
  { uid: '456', name: 'Insider B' },
  { uid: '789', name: 'Insider B' }
]
```

and my lambda function receives the collection thru `insiders` variable and I loop in each records. Inside loop I update the position of the records

```
module.exports.reorder = async (event) => {

  const klass = await getKlass.byEnv(process.env.STAGE, 'insider');
  const req = event.body
  var insiders = req.insiders;

  try {
    for (let [index, insider] of insiders.entries()) {
      console.log("Insider: ", insider);
      console.log("Index: ", index);
      await klass.update({ uid: insider.uid }, {
        $PUT: {
          position: index += 1
        }
      }, { condition: 'attribute_exists(uid)' })
    }
    return successResponse.message();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("===============");
    console.error(err);
    console.log("===============");
    if (err && err.code == 'ConditionalCheckFailedException') {
      return noRecord404.notFound();
    }
  }
}
```

this is working fine when I'm testing it in my local but when I deploy it to AWS Lambda It's not being updated. I also put `console.log` inside loop and I'm getting the printed log.

Comment: Need more info. Errors? What does cloudwatch say? Did you configure everything correctly?

Comment: @Mars there's no errors. It's just not updating the items inside dynamodb

Comment: Is your lambda script actually getting called? What are you logging to cloudwatch? Can't really say much with this limited info...

Comment: What is `klass` exactly? Show more of your code please.

Comment: @MarkB the klass is the modal related to the DB. for example I have insiders table so my klass is `Insider`

Comment: @Mars there's no error from CloudWatch. In fact I'm getting the console.log inside the loop.

Comment: @MarkB please check the updated code.

Comment: What does "getting the console.log inside the loop" mean? Once? 100 times?

Comment: If your logic is being performed inside klass.update, then we need to see klass.update